# Recuperar query string com caractere "+"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, querystring

Possuo em meu controller, um método onde eu pego uma *Query String*, descriptografo ela e utilizo os dados em minha consulta.
Porém, quando o valor criptografado possui um sinal de `+`, ele não é recuperado pelo `Request.QueryString`. Logo recebo um erro ao tentar descriptografar.

Segue meu controller:

```
 public ActionResult 
       {

            //Recebe a string Criptografada
            string param = Request.QueryString["param"];// Nesta Parte o sinal de + não é recuperado
            string nome = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(param);

            //Instancia obj da DLL
            Criptografia cr = new Criptografia();
            //Descriptografa a string
            string nomeDescrypt = cr.Decrypt(nome);// recebo o erro

            //Separa a string por meio do "|"
            string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "|" };
            var result = nomeDescrypt.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

            //Converte para o tipo de dado correto
            var matricula = Convert.ToInt32(result[0]);
            var contrato = Convert.ToInt32(result[1]);

            var usuarios = usuarioRepository.Lista.Where(r => r.CdMatricula == matriculaUser && r.SqContrato == contratoUser).FirstOrDefault();

            return View();
        }
```

**Exemplo de parâmetro passado:** *./?param=kmFxK8ID3ç+ZdGGbQN9oJA==*
**O que é recuperado:** *./?param=kmFxK8ID3ç ZdGGbQN9oJA==*

O sinal de `+` some, e fica um espaço no lugar.

Comment: Você quer recuperar o sinal no param? *Ex: param=foo+bar*, é pra retornar foo+bar?

Comment: @Laerte editei a pergunta com o que preciso.
É exatamente isso.  "foo+bar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` tem um significado semântico na query string. É usado para representar espaço.

Se você quer obter o literal `+` na sua query string, você precisa trocar o `+` pelo percent-encoding dele: `%2B`

*Exemplo: ./?param=foo%2Bbar*
No seu code-behind irá retornar: `foo+bar`

Outra forma, é substituindo o `+` pelo `%2B` via programação:

```
string param = Request.QueryString["param"];
string nome = param != null ? HttpUtility.UrlDecode(param.Replace(" ", "%2B")) : "";
```

Comment: O problema é que essa Query String está sendo passado para mim, por outra aplicação, que eu não tenho acesso.
Não existe uma forma de eu tratar isso em meu controller não?

Comment: Complementei a pergunta, verifique se resolve seu problema.

Comment: A string nome aparece o sinal de +, porém ao utilizar o *Url.Decode*, ele volta como o espaço novamente.

Comment: Você só precisa do sinal de `+`, certo?

Comment: Eu só preciso substituir o *espaço* pelo sinal de +

Comment: Pronto, eu também coloquei uma verificação caso o **param** for nulo.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que precisava. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o método `replace()` para substituir esse espaço em branco!